# Установка успешно скаченных пакетов в MSYS2 после ряда неудач при загрузке

Tags: windows, qt, msys2

Устанавливаю по официальному [мануалу](https://wiki.qt.io/MSYS2) в MSYS2 всё необходимое для работы с Qt5. Вся часть пакетов непосредственно касающихся Qt5 скачалась и встала без проблем, однако при исполнении
`pacman -S base-devel git mercurial cvs wget p7zip pacman perl ruby python2 mingw-w64-i686-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` вышел ряд ошибок (всего пакетов на ~7МБ):  `не удалось получить файл 'automake1.11-1.11.6-3-any.pkg.tar.xz' из repo.msys2.org : The requested URL returned error: 404`. Ну ладно, подумал я, однако после загрузки увидел не установку успешно скаченных пакетов, а ошибку: `ошибка: не удалось завершить транзакцию (непредвиденная ошибка) Обнаружены ошибки, пакеты не обновлены.`

Как же мне установить уже скаченные пакеты, игнорируя возникшие ошибки?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была связана с отзывом ключа одного из сотрудников MSYS2.ORG, что повлекло такие беды для хомячков. Однако [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195062/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-msys2) проблемы с ключами  после рестарта MSYS решило названную в топике трудность.