# Ошибка ключей при обновлении MSYS2

Tags: windows, msys2

Обновляю MSYS2. Пишу: `pacman -Sy`, а он мне ошибку с ключом:
`ошибка: msys: неизвестный ключ "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04"` и `ошибка: key "4A6129F4E4B84AE46ED7F635628F528CF3053E04" could not be looked up remotely`, затем качает некоторые пакеты типа mingw64 и mingw64.sig, но в конце выдает `ошибка: failed to synchronize all databases`.
Как же мне обновить детину, если он при прямом подключении к интернету при попытке ломается описанным образом, хоть снова переустанавливай (после поломки ключа другие обычные пакеты уже не ставит).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашел по [ссылке](http://pacman%20-Syu):

> Оказалось, что Alexey Pavlov (Alexpux) alexpux@gmail.com; больше не занимается подписанием пакетов, соответственно его ключ был отозван, так что нам нужно обновить PGP ключи MSYS2.

Загружаем и устанавливаем новые ключи:

```
$ curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz 
$ curl -O http://repo.msys2.org/msys/x86_64/msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz.sig 
$ pacman -U --config <(echo) msys2-keyring-r21.b39fb11-1-any.pkg.tar.xz
```

И, на всякий случай, очистим хранилище PGP ключей и обновим его содержимое:

```
$ rm -r /etc/pacman.d/gnupg/ 
$ pacman-key --init 
$ pacman-key --populate msys2
```

А теперь радостно запускаем обновление:

```
pacman -Syu
```